# How to Publish (deploy) local (.war .jar) files to Artifactory using Gradle version 1.12?

Tags: java, maven, gradle, artifactory

**How to Publish (deploy) local (.war .jar) files to Artifactory using Gradle version 1.12?**

Dear all

I'm having a hard time trying to make this because of the older version of Gradle that I can not change because specifications, I would be very gratefully if someone can help me with this code.

What I have done till now:

```
   buildscript {
        repositories {
            maven { url 'http://jcenter.bintray.com' }
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath(group: 'org.jfrog.buildinfo', name: 'build-info-extractor-gradle', version: '3.0.1')
        }
    }
    apply plugin: com.jfrog.artifactory-upload'
    artifactory {
        contextUrl = 'http://my.domain.com/artifactory/'  
        resolve {
            repository {
                repoKey = 'remote-deploy'
                maven = true
            }
        }
    }

NOTE: I don't know how to set my the local files to be uploaded but I read that I can use something like this "$rootDir\build\lib\buildProject.war"
```

> ```
> With the suggestions I made this changes in my code:
> ```

apply plugin: 'com.jfrog.artifactory-upload'
    apply plugin: 'maven-publish'
    apply plugin: 'maven'
    apply plugin: 'distribution'

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'http://jcenter.bintray.com' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath(group: 'org.jfrog.buildinfo', name: 'build-info-extractor-gradle', version: '2.2.5')
    }
    configurations {
        published
    }
}

artifactoryPublish.skip = true
task sourceJar(type: Jar){
    from file("build/libs/"+project.archivesBaseName2+".jar")
    classifier = 'sources'
}
artifacts{
    archives sourceJar
    published sourceJar
}
artifactory {
    contextUrl = 'http://www site com/artifactory/'
    publish {
        contextUrl = 'http://www site com/artifactory/'   //The base Artifactory URL for the publisher
        //A closure defining publishing information
        repository {
            repoKey = 'jarDeploy'
            username = 'user'
            password = 'pass'
        }
        defaults{
        //This closure defines defaults for all 'artifactoryPublish' tasks of all projects the plugin is applied to

            properties{
                //Optional closure to attach properties to artifacts based on a list of artifact patterns per project publication
                mavenJava 'org.jfrog:*:*:*@*', key1: 'val1'

                publicationName 'group:module:version:classifier@type', key1:'value1', key2:'value2'
            }
            publishBuildInfo = true   //Publish build-info to Artifactory (true by default)
            publishArtifacts = true   //Publish artifacts to Artifactory (true by default)
            publishPom = true   //Publish generated POM files to Artifactory (true by default).
            publishIvy = false   //Publish generated Ivy descriptor files to Artifactory (true by default).
        }
    }
    resolve{
        contextUrl = 'http://www site com/artifactory/'   //The base Artifactory URL for the resolver
        repository{
            repoKey = 'jarDeploy'  //The Artifactory (preferably virtual) repository key to resolve from
            username = 'user'       //Optional resolver user name (leave out to use anonymous resolution)
            password = 'pass'   //The resolver password
            maven = true                //Resolve Maven-style artifacts and descriptors (true by default)
        }
    }
}
```

Now I see Build publications on Arctifactory but are empty no files to download
[image]

```
[buildinfo] Properties file path was not found! (Relevant only for builds running on a CI Server)
Creating properties on demand (a.k.a. dynamic properties) has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed
 in Gradle 2.0. Please read http://gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.plugins.ExtraPropertiesExtensi
on.html for information on the replacement for dynamic properties.
Deprecated dynamic property: "publishPom" on "task ':api:artifactoryPublish'", value: "true".
Deprecated dynamic property: "publishIvy" on "task ':api:artifactoryPublish'", value: "false".
Deprecated dynamic property "publishPom" created in multiple locations.
Deprecated dynamic property "publishIvy" created in multiple locations.
:webapp:artifactoryPublish                
Deploying build info to: http://www site com/artifactory/api/build
Build successfully deployed. Browse it in Artifactory under http://tc-scm.bitnamiapp.com/artifactory/webapp/
builds/leadgnome-services/1423748387989/2015-02-12T09:39:45.642-0400/

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
```

Comment: I Update the code following your git example, now I can see the Build in Artifactory but no file in it. this is the result of the gradle artifactorybuild

Answer (score 0):

Artifactory plugin uploads a file set that is prepared by another plugin. Considering your version of Gradle, that will probably be the `maven` plugin.

`maven` plugin creates and populates a `configuration` (usually called `archives`) which contains the files it built. This configuration needs to be specified in the `artifactory` closure.

You can see number of examples [here](https://github.com/JFrogDev/project-examples/tree/master/gradle-example).

P.S. The 3.0.1 version of the plugin won't probably work with such and old Gradle. Please check [the docs](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Using+Older+Versions+of+Gradle) for the compatibility matrix.

Comment: Thank you very much but I have no luck yet, I try to use the examples in the github following your instruction, but I'm still unable of uploading any file in the Artifactory. The plugin seems to be working with the version 3.0.1 and also 2.2.5, but while I cant publish anything I'm not sure.

Comment: Did you add the `configuration` to the closure? If so, please update the question with the relevant code.

Comment: [code]buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'http://jcenter.bintray.com' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-plugin:1.0'
        classpath(group: 'org.jfrog.buildinfo', name: 'build-info-extractor-gradle', version: '2.2.5')
    }
}
artifacts{
    homeDir = file('c:/file.war')
    archives homeDir
}[/code]

Comment: Please update the question. Comments are not the place to paste blocks of code.

Comment: Thank you I did, but now I cant see any file uploaded to the Artifactory Build just a publication as the picture above

Comment: `artifactory-upload` plugin works with `configurations`, not `publications` (as opposite to `artifactory` plugin). Please consult the documentation (and the relevant examples).

Comment: Links are dead.