# publish final jar file in artifactory using gradle

Tags: gradle, artifactory

I am trying to publish jar file (output of a gradle project) to jfrog/artifactory. The project is successful when I execute `gradlew build` or `gradlew build artifactoryPublish`. I also see on console that `Build successfully deployed. Browse it in Artifactory under https://...` but when I go to Artifactory the nothing is there. I tried following the [jfrog/artifactory documentation](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Gradle+Artifactory+Plugin), some questions on stackoverflow like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28456312/how-to-publish-deploy-local-war-jar-files-to-artifactory-using-gradle-vers) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25279001/nothing-published-to-artifactory-using-gradle-artifactory-plugin). Following is the snippet from my build.gradle

```
 buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        
    }
    dependencies {
        //Check for the latest version here: http://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/com.jfrog.artifactory
        classpath "org.jfrog.buildinfo:build-info-extractor-gradle:4+"
    }
}

plugins {
    // Apply the java-library plugin to add support for Java Library
    id 'java-library'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'
}


apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

allprojects {
    apply plugin: "com.jfrog.artifactory"   
}

repositories {
    // Use jcenter for resolving dependencies.
    // You can declare any Maven/Ivy/file repository here.
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    // This dependency is exported to consumers, that is to say found on their compile classpath.
    api 'org.apache.commons:commons-math3:3.6.1'

    // This dependency is used internally, and not exposed to consumers on their own compile classpath.
    implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:29.0-jre'

    // Use JUnit test framework
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13'
}

task sourceJar(type: Jar){
    from file("build/libs/mygradle-1.0.0-sources.jar")
    classifier = 'sources'
}

task certify(type: Zip, group: 'build', dependsOn: 'build') {
    from ("build.gradle")
    from ("libs") 
    from ("src/test")
    from ("build/libs")
    from ("${buildDir}/reports/tests")
    archiveFileName = "certify-resources.zip"
    destinationDirectory = file("${buildDir}/certify")
}

version  = '1.0.0'
group = 'com.mypro.test'                // this is the package prefix the jar will go into artifactory

artifacts {
    archives sourceJar
}

publishing {
    publications {
        pluginJar(MavenPublication) {
            groupId "${group}"
            artifactId 'mygradle'                         // this is the package suffix the jar will go into in artifactory
            version "${version}"
            artifact sourceJar
            from components.java
        }
    }
}

artifactory {
    contextUrl = "${artifactory_contextUrl}"   //The base Artifactory URL if not overridden by the publisher/resolver
    publish {
        repository {
            repoKey = 'gradle-release-local'
            username = "${artifactory_user}"
            password = "${artifactory_password}"
            maven = true
            
        }
    }
    resolve {
        repository {
            repoKey = 'gradle-dev'
            username = "${artifactory_user}"
            password = "${artifactory_password}"
            maven = true
            
        }
    }
}
```

I am not sure what I am missing. Could anyone suggest what I missed. Thanks

EDIT: I created new instance of rhel/artifactory and a new gradle project just to be sure that the issue is not coming from somewhere else but still

only this information Build-info successfully deployed. Browse it in `Artifactory under http://100.100.11.11:8081/artifactory/webapp/builds/mygradle/1675035714284` is showing when I execute `gradlew build artifactoryPublish` with

> BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JAR component can be extracted from components.java.

Try to add it to the publication as following:

```java
pluginJar(MavenPublication) {
    groupId "${group}"
    artifactId 'my-published-project'
    version "${version}"
    artifact sourceJar

    from components.java // <- add this line
}
```

> the java component in its default setup consists of a JAR — produced by the jar task

For more information see [Component terminology](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_management_terminology.html#sub:terminology_component) and [Maven publications](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/publishing_maven.html#publishing_maven:publications).

EDIT:
Also, since "pluginJar" is not a default publication name, we should add the publication to the list (the plugin adds mavenJava and ivyJava by default).

```java
artifactory {
    contextUrl = "${artifactory_contextUrl}"   //The base Artifactory URL if not overridden by the publisher/resolver
    publish {
        repository {
            repoKey = 'gradle-release-local'
            username = "${artifactory_user}"
            password = "${artifactory_password}"
            maven = true
            
        }
        defaults {
            publications('pluginJar') // <- add this
        }
    }
...
}
```

Comment: I added 'component.java' and still the same. It is not pushing the jar to artifactory

Comment: @Karan see my edit